# How to import HTML/JS into Drupal?

Tags: javascript, html, drupal, pybossa

I have a few html and javascript programs that outline a webpage with a user-interactive tasks. The files work in PyBossa (http://pybossa.com/) but I want to incorporate them in my Drupal website. I am very new to Drupal and am not sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you need to do, you'll either want to expose it via a custom module or, more likely, through a theme. You'll need to specify your Drupal version and purpose for a better answer but, in general, you'll want to add the files to your theme_name.info file (for D7 and below) or theme_name.libraries.yml file in D8. You can also add it to your template.php (D7 and below) or you theme_name.theme file.

We need more info for your Drupal version and the specific use case. As you can see, there are many ways.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own theme to add your own html and js code in it but in drupal file format and standard, so read this [article](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming) to create a custom theme in drupal 7